# Rails not displaying unicode character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

If I print the string `"hello\u1D175 \u1D176and goodbye"`, I expect a musical tie symbol to show. Instead I get `"helloᴗ5 ᴗ6and goodbye"`.

I'm assuming I need to change how the string is read? Or the font?

Answer (score 0):

Using the unicode decimal value for a musical tie symbol, the following should work

```
 9835.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

For example,

```
 "hello #{9835.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)} and..."
```

Reference: https://unicodelookup.com/

Comment: `"\u12345"` works fine, I don't need to use the decimal value. The problem is the specific characters I'm using—they seem to use a code that's longer than normal, and not accepted with the default setup (the character you're referring to is not what I'm referring to)